# $D\to~T-Alg$ is injective on objects

Tags: category-theory

Let $D$ be a monad.  I’m trying to prove that the Kleisli category $D_T$ is equivalent to the full subcategory of T-Alg whose objects are all $\mu_X:T^2X\to TX$ for $X\in Ob(D)$. Call the latter category E. There is a fairly obvious functor $D_T\to E$ sending X to $\mu_X:T^2X\to TX$, and $f:X \to TY$ to $\mu_Y \circ T(f)$. This is obviously surjective on objects and I can show it's bijective on hom sets. But I have trouble proving it is injective on objects.  Basically can you recover $X$ from $\mu_X:T^2X\to TX$?

Comment: I don't know if it will necessarily be injective on objects.  But it should be enough to show it's injective on isomorphism classes of objects; and for that, it should be sufficient to show your functor is fully faithful.  That, in turn, should be easy from the definition, I think - after all, you know that $\operatorname{Hom}_{T-Alg}((TX, \mu_X), (TY, \mu_Y)) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_D(X, TY) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{D_T}(X, Y)$ so all that remains to show is that your functor induces exactly this bijection.

Comment: @DanielSchepler oh yeah i forgot equivalence only needs a pseudo inverse.  but so is my pseudo-inverse just like a choice-function on the classes $\{X\in Ob(D): \mu_X = \mu_Y\}, Y\in Ob(D)$?  it gives me a little bit of ZFC anxiety...

Comment: Yeah, I think in the general proof that a functor which is essentially surjective and fully faithful is an equivalence - that proof does rely on choice.  And you're right, I don't see any easy way to avoid using choice in defining a pseudoinverse for this particular case, either.

Comment: And for an example where a monad collapses isomorphism classes, consider the example where the category is the poset category of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, and the monad is the one which sends a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to its closure.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yeah i mean particularly because these aren't small categories so it's not immediately clear to me how we even use AC.  But i will try not to dwell on abstract nonsense.  thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, if you're working with foundations that include the notion of small set, then in general I think you still require the objects to form a set (as opposed to allowing a proper class) - just the set of objects is not necessarily a small set.  And yes, as far as I know, if you do allow a proper class of objects, then that result on essentially surjective and fully faithful functors will probably require a Hilbert epsilon operator ("global choice") as opposed to the axiom of choice ("local" or "small choice").

Comment: Yes, category theory depends on some kind of choice axiom for proper classes, but this is totally independent from the concrete question you're asking. Just prove that $D_T\to E$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective, and study the proof that such a functor has a quasi-inverse under global choice separately if you want to.